# Prevent restoring of focus when closing popup menu opened on mouse over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am using [@material-ui](https://material-ui.com) with react. I've got the following problem:

I have an input component and a popup menu, that opens on mouse over.
When the menu opens, the input component loses focus.
When the menu closes, focus is restored to the input component.

I need to prevent the restoration of the focus to the input element.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import { FormControl } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleCloseAndRemoveFocus = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current);
    if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.blur();
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Input autoFocus inputRef={inputRef} />
        <Button onMouseDown={handleCloseAndRemoveFocus}>Clear focus</Button>
        <Button
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onMouseOver={handleClick}
        >
          Hover to open
        </Button>
      </FormControl>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Return to focused</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseAndRemoveFocus}>Clear focus</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-http-v9vji?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `disableRestoreFocus=true` on your Menu component. This will prevent the previously focused element to restore its focus once the menu/modal is hidden.

```js
<Menu
  id="simple-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={handleClose}
  disableRestoreFocus={true}
>
  ...
</Menu>
```

This prop is documented on [Modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/) but works for `Menu` too, this is because Menu is built on top of Modal.

[image: Edit reverent-goldstine-uyqvz]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find this solution. The documentation did not find it when searching for 'focus'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `disableAutoFocus` on `Menu` component

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: can you please explain why ?